# Change column type from “Lookup (information already on this site)” to Person or Group

Tags: list, lookup-column, column

I have an issue after migration SharePoint 2007 to 2010. We had “Person or Group” which now somehow has transformed to “Lookup (information already on this site)”. This creates lots of troubles for our team, as now is it displayed with lots of ## and some other information which we don’t want. Also adding new users is not user friendly.

Any idea how to change column type from “Lookup (information already on this site)” to “Person or Group”?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me where the lookup is pointing to and what kind of data it is?